# Unable to install typescript compiler 'typescript@https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/typescript/-/typesc....' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I tried to install typescript compiler on linux by running this

> sudo npm i -g typescript

But, I keep getting this error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/typescript/-/typescript-5.1.3.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'typescript@https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/typescript/-/typescript-5.1.3.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2023-06-04T11_50_28_794Z-debug.log
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Your custom registry doesn't have the package.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't run `npm install` as root. It will install to your $HOME by itself, and if you are already logged in as root (probably not a good idea to begin with), it will be able to write to `/root` already.